# The use of "therefore" before an imperative

Tags: grammar, imperatives

Is it correct to write "therefore do not" in a sentence? Obviously I've seen it being used in the Bible but not a lot else where.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with it. Both *therefore* and *do not* are a little formal: a more colloquial form would be *so don't ...*

Answer (score 0):

I have always found that citing a usage precedent from the Bible (KJV) suffices to silence any carping copy-editor, so feel free to use *therefore* to introduce an imperative. In  so doing, you are flagging the logical relationship between that imperative and what has gone before, namely *reasons* for doing (or refraining from doing) as you bid.

This kind of reasoning, according to a distinction that I particularly associate with George Campbell’s *Philosophy of Rhetoric* (Bk. I Ch. i),  is a matter of *persuading* one’s audience *to* act or refrain, as distinct from *convincing* them *that* such-and-such is or is not the case (which would involve *therefore*’s introducing an *indicative* clause). Most modern usages of *therefore* have for context efforts to *convince,* not *persuade,* in these terms. Where the context is an effort to persuade, *so* is often preferred over *therefore,* not necessarily as less formal but as a little less ostentatiously logical. The decline of *therefore* with imperative may be attributable to a decline in the faith in reason as guide to conduct.

Comment: I'm writing hostel regulations so I guess I could be a little formal. Thanks for answering!